# JVM Memory Defaults

Tags: java, memory, jvm

What is the default Xms and Xmx settings for the Sun JVM (v 1.4*) if those values are not specified at startup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [documented](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/linux/java.html):

- Xmx: default 64M
- Xms: default 2M

That's for Linux, but I've checked and the values are the same for [Windows](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) and [Solaris](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html) too. Don't rely on that being the case for other versions or options though. In particular, the choice of server or client VM depends on operating system, at least in later versions.

[Another piece of documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html)

Comment: I know the question was for 1.4 but you can find one for Java 6 at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Answer (score 7):

From [Sun's tooldocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html):

> -Xmsn
>       Specify the initial size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.
>   This value must be a multiple of 1024
>   greater than 1MB. Append the letter k
>   or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M
>   to indicate megabytes. The default
>   value is 2MB. Examples:
>
> ```
>            -Xms6291456
>            -Xms6144k
>            -Xms6m
> ```
>
> -Xmxn
>       Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.
>   This value must a multiple of 1024
>   greater than 2MB. Append the letter k
>   or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M
>   to indicate megabytes. The default
>   value is 64MB. Examples:
>
> ```
>            -Xmx83886080
>            -Xmx81920k
>            -Xmx80m
> ```

So 2MB and 64MB.

(The link above is for the 1.5 docs, but you can download the 1.4 docs, and they say the same thing.)

Comment: Is it the same in 1.4, though?

Comment: As it happens, yes... but I've linked the 1.4 docs in my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'd linked to the 1.5 docs because when I tried to get the 1.4 docs it redirected me to a download page. Apparently 1.4.2 doesn't do this yet, though.